# Skype for business - Error on CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint operations

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

Around 2 weeks ago I have written an Azure bot using Node.js SDK v4 and linked it to Skype for Business successfully. Later on I decided to switch it to use SDK v3 instead because of some issues.

I have then removed the bot from Azure and recreated a new one with same name, but I have not unlinked it from Skype for Business.

Now I am trying to link this new bot to Skype for Business. I have set the channel on Azure and following this [instructions](https://skypeappregistration.azurewebsites.net/bot/%3C%3CBOT-ID%3E%3E) (slightly different to import session, because MFA is enabled).

Once I try to issue New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint command, it says that endpoint already exists. But if I try to issue Remove-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint the endpoint is not found.

[Image of commands execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3x8d.png)

How can I get this bot setup?

Thanks

Edit:
Commands executed on Powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Import-Module LyncOnlineConnector
$session = New-CsOnlineSession
Import-PSSession $session
Remove-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -Uri sip:<<bot_uri>>
New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint -ApplicationId <<bot_id>> -Name <<bot_name>> -Uri sip:<<bot_uri>>
```

Comment: Are you using a different sip for the new bot?  Please review this extensive answer from jesus-Seijas-sp: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4647#issuecomment-397411409

Comment: I have tried with a completely new bot before and it returned some errors doing the same steps. Today I have just tried with the real bot, changing sip, and it has returned successfully, although it is not available on Skype yet. I will check again in 8 hours. Thanks.